# Weighted average with values itself as the weight

Tags: convex-analysis, arithmetic, average, convex-hulls

A weighted average for the collection of numbers $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ is defined as,

$({\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i})/({\sum_{i=1}^n w_i})$

where $w_i$ is the weight of $x_i$. Is there any specific term for the special case when $\forall i, w_i=x_i$ and $x_i\in [0,1]$?

If not what will be the interpretation of the weighted average in this special case?

Comment: In what you've written that fraction is always $1$ unless all the $w_i = x_i = 0$. Please edit to say what you mean, and provide a few examples. (I don't think what you want has a name, but let's see exactly what it is first.)

Comment: @EthanBolker: Why would it be $1$? It's just $\sum x_i^2/\sum x_i$. For example, if $n=2$ and $x_1=x_2=1/2$, then it is $(1/4+1/4)/(1/2+1/2) = 1/2$, not $1$.

Comment: I thought $x_i \in [0,1]$ meant $x_i = 0$ or $1$. Sorry.I wouldn't call this a weighted average. Why not just ask for a name for $\Sigma x_i^2 / \Sigma x_i$? (I don't know a name for that)? It's some relative of variance/mean in statistics, and may have a name there. Perhaps ask instead at stats.stackexchange,com.

Comment: It came up in a context of weighted average. So I just wrote it in that form. But I will see if it has a name in statistics.